# There is no implicit conversion between 'PartialViewResult' and 'JsonResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got the error when using conditional operator:

```
public ActionResult Topic()
{
   var model = new TopicMasterViewModel();
   // do something...
   return model.Topic != null && model.Topic.Count > 0 ? PartialView("../Home/_Topic", model) : Json(new { });
}
```

The error said that:

> > Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between **'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult'** and **'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'**

Why? `ActionResult` can return both `PartialView()` and `Json()`

Answer (score 2):

The types `PartialViewResult` and `JsonResult` are not implicitly convertable/casable so,In ternary operator, the return type of both cases should match which is not in this case.

You have to use normal if else here like:

```
if(model.Topic != null && model.Topic.Count > 0)
    return PartialView("../Home/_Topic", model) 
else
    return Json(new { });
```

Answer (score 0):

***For Ternary Operators:*** *The expression of a conditional operator has a specific type. Both types used in the expression must be of the same type or implicitly convertible to each other.*

While in your case `'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult'` and `'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'` are not implicitly covertible.

You can use a normal `if` condition for your case.